# EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY is ignored

Tags: android

I am trying to record a video with an Intent, and the quality of the video is high and the size is higher than 5mb.

I am using Samsung Galaxy S running android 4.2.2

Here is my code:

```
            Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
            // i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            // Uri.fromFile(FileUtils.getFileName(FileTypes.VIDEO)));
            i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
            i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 5242880);
            i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 45);
            startActivityForResult(i, Config.RECORD_VIDEO);
```

Comment: Did you mean : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S

Comment: Is Logcat showing sth ?

Comment: nothing special, the video records and shows with no issues other than the wrong quality and size being larger than the size limit.

Comment: did you manage to solve this in some way? I have the same problem on galaxy s2 running android 4.1...!

Comment: @lelloman I haven't managed to solve it, it seems like whatsapp has the same problem and they managed to 'solve' it by limiting the size of the video, the problem is caused because samsung has their own implementation for the video recorder application.

Comment: thanks, this is pure pain, damn samsung

Comment: EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY is deprecated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY)

It says that value 0 means low quality. You could change your value to 1.

And the value for 5Mb I would set to 5491520L.

All together could be:

```
import android.provider.MediaStore;
...


Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.VIDEO_CAPTURE);
...
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 5491520L);//5*1048*1048=5MB
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,45);
startActivityForResult(i, Config.RECORD_VIDEO);
```